# Serial Up-voting problem

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is so depressing. Yesterday, I opened up my account and found it had some 620 rep. Today it came down to 517. I was shocked at first. But then :

[image]

I think these serial voters must be removed. They cause **mental trauma**.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant users have gotten a suspension and/or have been removed.

Thank you for bringing this to our notice.

Comment: Intentionally vague wording? :D

Comment: @Doorknob I can neither confirm nor deny that there is a possibility that the genesis of this statement was, perhaps, made with the plausible intent of being, as you might have a propensity to say, equivocally ambiguous.

Comment: Heh................

Comment: This post is the craziest thing I have seen on Physics.SE so far. And _by far_...